# How do I shift all elements by 1 position after a certain index in an array? c#

Tags: c#

starting array --> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,null,null]
desired array --> [1,2,3,null,4,5,6,7,8,null]

Basically trying to shift all the array elements after 3rd index by 1 position; this will just create a gap in the array.

How can I do this using a for loop?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts.
 i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: that is correct, I have tried using for loop but keep getting confused at the part when i need to stop. So in the for loops condition, `for (int i = num_of_valid_ints; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: I know that I have to go backwards in the loop but if i need to stop at the 3rd position and add a number or null what is the maths behind that?

Comment: You should add your failed attempt to the question, rather than adding it in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this right rotation of elements in-place without creating an additional array.

The algorithm is something like this:

Store the last element, iterate backwards from the last position in the array, shift the elements by one and finally insert the last element at the third index:

```
int?[] arr = new int?[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, null, null };
const int StartIndex = 3;

int? last = arr[arr.Length - 1];
for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i > StartIndex; i--)
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
arr[StartIndex] = last;
```